# How to display score in the canvas using Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cant display the score at my winPanel in canvas.

Score coding and UI which display on the game scene:-

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class getscore : MonoBehaviour

{
    public GameObject scoretext;

    private void Start()
    {
        scoretext.GetComponent<Text>().text = "0";
    }

    public void setscore(float scoretoadd)
    {
        float currentscore = float.Parse(scoretext.GetComponent<Text>().text);
        float newscore = currentscore + scoretoadd;
        scoretext.GetComponent<Text>().text = newscore.ToString("F0");
    }
}
```

[image]

Next, I put the same coding in the canvas where its supposed display the score at my winPanel canvas:-

[image]

Output where the score only display on the game scene but not displayed at my winPanel in canvas:-

[image]

The problem now is... why the score did not display in my winPanel canvas?

Comment: It's hard to tell as you didn't provide enough information. Please also share the code calling the 'setscore' function.
My bet is that your 'newscore' variable isn't being correctly calculated. Its value remains 0.

Comment: Does your winPanel use the `getscore` script?

Comment: try to debug first the score itself Debug.Log(newscrore) and see what is the results.

2nd, are u sure you called setscore() function when the game end?

Comment: Bishok: I already gave you the coding of setscore(); @Haytam yes...

Comment: @OmarVector I'm not sure hmmmm.... can you help me Omar?

Comment: you are actually declared the function but you are not showing us where you are calling it show us complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend saving the score in a static float, so it's the same number, no matter where you access it from:

```
public class getscore : MonoBehaviour

{
    public GameObject scoretext;
    public static float score = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        setscore(0);
    }

    public void setscore(float scoretoadd)
    {
        score += scoretoadd;
        scoretext.GetComponent<Text>().text = score.ToString("F0");
    }
}
```

Remember to set the score to 0 again when reloading the level `getscore.score = 0`